# Line heading on sides not appear in firefox

Tags: css

Hello guys today i have a problems with compatibility with css and firefox, the issue is when i enter to my website www.fashoop.com you canse some line headers on sides, like this:

```
 (GOOGLE CHROME EXAMPLE)
```

COLOR BLUE    AND     COLOR CYAN

------------TITLE----------------

and this effect work fine on google chrome but the issue presents when you enter with firefox explorer the line of one side dissapear and automatically put points like this:

```
 (FIREFOX EXAMPLE)
```

COLOR BLUE    AND     COLOR CYAN

------------TITLE....

Any here know why its happend in firefox?, i hope can help me guys! here the link of the website www.fashoop.com thanks!

CODE:

```
span.section-title{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

    font: 1.6em/1.1 Georgia;
    padding: .2em 0;
    }
span.section-title:before,
span.section-title:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;

    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #000;
    }
span.section-title:before {    
    left: -.5em;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
    background: #ef387a;
    }
span.section-title:after {    
    left: .5em;
    margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
    background: #1c77bd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is deal breaker for `span.section-title` or use narrower `span.section-title:before, span.section-title:after`...
Anyway there is lots of options how you can fix this